# After upgrading to Java 8u292, TLS connection fails with SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, ssl, sslhandshakeexception

I have a LXC CentOS 7 host running WildFly 21.0.2. The application server connects to a MariaDB 10.4.18 database using a two-way TLS connection (mutual authentication) and the MySQL Connector/J 5.1.47 JDBC driver. It worked fine until the upgrade from Java 8u282 to Java 8u292 that happened yesterday. The connection now fails with these errors:

```
IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
```

My first thought is that Java 8u292 deprecated the protocol or the cipher suite that was used to establish the connection by MySQL Connector/J 5.1.47 JDBC driver.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [Consolidated Release Notes for JDK 8 and JDK 8 Update Releases](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/8all-relnotes.html), indicates that [TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 have been disabled in Java 8u292](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8202343) and my goal was since to force the connection to use TLS 1.2.

I tried upgrading the JDBC drivers to MySQL Connector/J 5.1.49, which is the latest version at this time, but nothing improved.

Finally, the [enabledTLSProtocols](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-connp-props-security.html#cj-conn-prop_enabledTLSProtocols) seemed the best option and connection was successfully established by the application server after adding `enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2` in the connection URL.